# How do I clean cooking oil off a steel fence?

Tags: cleaning, fence, oil

My next door neighbor decided to saturate panels of our steel fence with cooking oil to stop the rust (which was expected and is a desired patina).

How can we get rid of the old oil smell and get the oily stain off the fence?

Answer (score 6):

Knowing that you don't mind the rust, I'd go at it the same way you would dirty dishes soiled with the same thing--dish detergent and water. A little scrubbing with a nylon brush shouldn't damage the surface, and the rust will return shortly.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use something that is non-toxic and biodegradable since it is outdoors.

I would recommend using car wash soap, and wash it the same way as you would with your car. It has degreasers in it, and is usually safe. Mix a small amount with hot water, and scrub the fence with a stiff bristled broom. Spray the fence with water, and then scrub with the soapy water and let it sit for a few minutes, and then rinse.

You may need to repeat a few times to get all of the oil off. A pressure washer will speed up the process.

Comment: Are most car wash soaps non-toxic and biodegradable? They often leave "protective" residues behind by design.

Comment: There are many soaps out now that use naturally-derived surfactants and claim to be non-toxic and biodegradable. If your store has an "organic" store brand (Stop and Shop in Massachusetts has "Nature's Promise"), start by looking for that brand in the cleaning aisle.

Answer (score 2):

Most solvents will remove oil. if you really want to strip the oil quickly brake cleaner is amazing and bare metal starts rusting quickly after cleaning [with this product](http://www.tooltopia.com/3m-automotive-8180.aspx?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=paid_search_google_pla&scid=scplp6821941&sc_intid=MMM8180&gclid=CL6C5qnsyM4CFURffgod0H4Duw). I use it quite a bit and it is one of the best degreasers  I have found.

Comment: I'd be reluctant to dump that much of a caustic solvent into my yard or the air if I had other options. How do plants react to it?

Comment: It evaporates very fast, I do not think it is a caustic. I have never gotten it on plants so I am not sure but it kills yellow jackets quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Simple Green is a degreaser, it's biodegradable and non-toxic.  If you could stand up a sheet of 4 x 8 plywood behind the fence and hit it with a power washer, that'd be great (probably).  But if not, apply some good ol' elbow grease.